# In PHP, how to convert a date in oW format into a timestamp?

Tags: php

I have a date in `oW` format. This is the 4 digit year in ISO 8601 format followed by the week number. As an example, 201301 represents the week starting on Monday, Dec. 31, 2012.

How can I convert this back to a timestamp. Going from timestamp to string works with `date('oW',$ts)`. How do I go backwards? I am interested in getting the Monday of the week represented in oW format. It would be very silly if PHP provided a way to go in one direction ut did not bother with the inverse.

Comment: I might be wrong, but "oW" cannot be translated into a timestamp again? Not with any kind of accuracy anyway?

Comment: `DateTime::createFromFormat` unfortunately cannot parse `'oW'` as a date. ='(

Comment: @RocketHazmat; It wouldn't matter since "oW" is a format of year and week, thus a specific date or time cannot be determined.

Comment: I understand that oW refers to a week. I need to get the Monday of that week, which refers to a concrete day. MySQL does this nicely.

Comment: @Daniel: Clearly it has week-resolution. Doesn't mean you can't convert it to a timestamp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ISO 8601 expects week dates in the following format:

```
YYYY\WWW
```

For example:

2012W52

is the start of the 52st week in 2012 what is actually the 2012/12/24.

To convert week dates back into a timestamp you can use the php function `strtotime()`. The code will look like follows:

```
$oW = '2012W53';
$time = strtotime($oW);
// will output: 2012-12-31T00:00:00+01:00 (I'm in CEST)
echo date('c', $time);
```

However the format you posted above - 201300 - cannot being understood by `strtotime()`. There are two problems :

- 00 is not allowed for the week. Allowed values for week are from 01 to 53
- You missed the 'W' in the middle. But it belongs to the ISO 8601 standard.

In my tests I further figured out, that 2012W53 points to the 2012/12/31 not 2013W00 (or W01 as you may think)

Further you may read [this comment in the php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php#105344) and the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) on this.

Comment: That's not how the ISO 8601 year and week number system works. Furthermore `201302` is not OP's example, it's `201300`, which, with your code, produces `1970-01-01T00:00:00+00:00`.

Comment: +1 nice update! I just investigated whether `201300` was actually valid to begin with, and having skimmed the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), it doesn't seem to mention `00` as valid week number indeed. I could be wrong though.

Comment: PS.: the format `2013W01` (without the dash) seems to be a valid one for `strtotime()` as well.